# 3rd toggle key not working C#

Tags: c#

Hi guys I've got this console application nearly all works but my toggle key 3 doesn't seem to work!

When you Press both the keys and specified code executes but with the third on it does not

```
    //These are the strings that inshlise the execution of the code
    String extention = String.Empty;

    //Gets the folder location
    DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.System));

    Console.WriteLine("Welcome Select An Option!");
    Console.WriteLine("Please Press Key 1 To List All Files In: C:\\Windows");
    Console.WriteLine("Please Press Key 1 To Filter File Types!");
    Console.WriteLine("Please Press Key 3 To Folder Statistics");
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInput = Console.ReadKey();

    if (KeyInput.KeyChar.Equals('1'))
    {
        //Here's where all the varibles declerd
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\Windows");

        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)
        {
            string path = filePaths[i];
            Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
    }

    if (KeyInput.KeyChar.Equals('2'))
    {
        //While begins
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(" :Leave Blank And Press Enter To End Loop - Please Enter Extention type!: ");

            //Here the file type enterd is loged ready for use! 
            extention = Console.ReadLine();
            //This will end the loop if the user don't input anything
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(extention))
            break;

            //This where the file type the user ented is added
            FileInfo[] files = root.GetFiles(@"*" + extention);
            //Gets files within
            foreach (var file in files)
            Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
        }
    }

    if (KeyInput.KeyChar.Equals('3'))
    {
        // Here's where data is vollected from C:\\Windows
        System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"C:\\Windows");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // This helps find the file location
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.RootDirectory;

        // This displays the files in the folder loacation
        System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");

        // This shows the folder sitstics of C:\\ windows
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo finfo in fileNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", finfo.Name, finfo.LastAccessTime, finfo.Length);
        }
    }

    // This is the code for the escape toggle key
    ConsoleKeyInfo esclink;

    Console.WriteLine("Press Escape key to exit!");
    do
    {
        esclink = Console.ReadKey();
        // This waits till the escape key is pressed and then takes action
    }
    while (esclink.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
   }
}
```

Comment: What errors/problems are you getting?

Comment: Basically when you press key 3 the number 3 just pops up in the console window and doesn't do anything and 1 and 2 do exactly as they should and want to know how I could fix it!

Comment: Try stepping through the code in debug mode. Perhaps one of the variables you expect to have information actually does not.

Comment: Turns out I put a Console.ReadLine(); in and stopped the info from coming up! Thanks guys haha!!! lol cant believe it was something silly like that!

Answer (score 0):

In the third `if` statement, I'm guessing the `Console.ReadLine();` is your culprit. It's waiting for the enter key to be hit again before continuing.

Building of George's answer, surround the entire thing in a do-while loop:

```
do
{
ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInput = Console.ReadKey();

if (KeyInput.KeyChar.Equals('1'))
{
    //Here's where all the varibles declerd
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\Windows");

    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)
    {
        string path = filePaths[i];
        Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
    }
}

if (KeyInput.KeyChar.Equals('2'))
{
    //While begins
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write(" :Leave Blank And Press Enter To End Loop - Please Enter Extention type!: ");

        //Here the file type enterd is loged ready for use! 
        extention = Console.ReadLine();
        //This will end the loop if the user don't input anything
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(extention))
        break;

        //This where the file type the user ented is added
        FileInfo[] files = root.GetFiles(@"*" + extention);
        //Gets files within
        foreach (var file in files)
        Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
    }
}

if (KeyInput.KeyChar.Equals('3'))
{
    // Here's where data is vollected from C:\\Windows
    System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"C:\\Windows");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // This helps find the file location
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.RootDirectory;

    // This displays the files in the folder loacation
    System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");

    // This shows the folder sitstics of C:\\ windows
    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo finfo in fileNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", finfo.Name, finfo.LastAccessTime, finfo.Length);
    }
}

// This is the code for the escape toggle key
ConsoleKeyInfo esclink;

Console.WriteLine("Press Escape key to exit!");

}
while (KeyInput.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not because the 3rd key is not working. The loop is wrong. Move the read key and the logic into the loop. 
**Do something similar to the following:**

```
static void ProcessKeyPress(ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInput)
        {
            if (KeyInput.KeyChar.Equals('1'))
            {
                //Here's where all the varibles declerd
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\George Philip\\Projects\\TestHarness");
                for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)
                {
                    string path = filePaths[i];
                    Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
                }


            }


            if (KeyInput.KeyChar.Equals('2'))
            {
                //While begins
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write(" :Leave Blank And Press Enter To End Loop - Please Enter Extention type!: ");

                    //Here the file type enterd is loged ready for use! 
                    extention = Console.ReadLine();
                    //This will end the loop if the user don't input anything
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(extention))
                        break;

                    //This where the file type the user ented is added
                    FileInfo[] files = root.GetFiles(@"*" + extention);
                    //Gets files within
                    foreach (var file in files)
                        Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
                }
            }


            if (KeyInput.KeyChar.Equals('3'))
            {
                // Here's where data is vollected from C:\\Windows
                System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"C:\\Windows");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // This helps find the file location
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.RootDirectory;

                // This displays the files in the folder loacation
                System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");

                // This shows the folder sitstics of C:\\ windows
                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo finfo in fileNames)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", finfo.Name, finfo.LastAccessTime, finfo.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //These are the strings that inshlise the execution of the code
            String extention = String.Empty;
            //Gets the folder location
             DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\George Philip\\Projects\\TestHarness");

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome Select An Option!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please Press Key 1 To List All Files In: C:\\Windows");
            Console.WriteLine("Please Press Key 1 To Filter File Types!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please Press Key 3 To Folder Statistics");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");


            // This is the code for the escape togle key
            ConsoleKeyInfo esclink;

            Console.WriteLine("Press Escape key to exit!");

            esclink = Console.ReadKey();

            do
            {
                ProcessKeyPress(esclink);

                esclink = Console.ReadKey();


                // This waits till the escape key is pressed and then takes action
            }
            while (esclink.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
        }
```